# Multiple JOINs of possible properties in a 'flower' arrangement - acceptable design?

Tags: mysql, database-design, join, schema

I have a functionality that has multiple (7+) potential properties to be added via a central 'hub' table. In most cases there will only be one property assigned, but it's possible the user will want to add all. The id of the hub is used to search a intermediary table which then links to the content table if there is additional content for the property.

I suppose this is the normalized approach but I'm new to DB design. Is this at all the sensible approach to such a scenario?

**Additional details**

I don't know how to output DDLs or create these DB tables in Stack but will try to give a clearer example of what I'm currently doing:

Output:

```
output_id, output
Central: central_id, output_id, central_data
Central_2_A: central_id, property_A_id
Property_A: property_A_id, property_A
Central_2_B: central_id, property_B_id
Property_B: property_B_id, property_B
Central_2_C: central_id, property_C_id
Property_C: property_C_id, property_C
```

...and so on to F or G, or even more theoretically

```
knex('Central').select(
Central.central_id
Central.output_id
Central.central_data
Property_A.property_A_id
Property_A.property_A
Property_B.property_B_id
Property_B.property_B
Property_C.property_C_id
Property_C.property_C
)
.leftJoin('Central_2_A','Central_2_A.central_id','Central.central_id')
.leftJoin('Property_A','Property_A.property_A_id','Central_2_A.property_A_id')
.leftJoin('Central_2_B','Central_2_B.central_id','Central.central_id')
.leftJoin('Property_B','Property_B.property_B_id','Central_2_B.property_B_id')
.leftJoin('Central_2_C','Central_2_C.central_id','Central.central_id')
.leftJoin('Property_C','Property_C.property_C_id','Central_2_A.property_C_id')
```

As a side note, I'm using Knex.js.

Comment: Unclear yet... Show simplified (2-3 properties) DDLs for described structure.

Comment: Are these properties themselves the entities, or they are attributes only? Why you store them in separate tables - they are so different in their attributes? Why you do not use common M:N model (table `properties` with attributes `id`, `type` - A,B,C,... , `value`, and joining table `central_to_properties` with attributes `central_id` and `property_id`)?

Comment: My understanding was that it was not optimal to have lots of null fields. In most cases only one property is being used, or another, or another, sometimes two, rarely 3, but the user is given the option of adding any of them.

Comment: *My understanding was that it was not optimal to have lots of null fields* There will be no NULL entries in my proposed scheme. Except the case when the property exists and its value is NULL.

Comment: This schema design is clumsy, slow, verbose, and other things.  It smells like the infamous "Entity-Attribute-Value".

Comment: Rick James are you referring to what I posted or what Akina has suggested? If me then why does it smell? Why the ambiguity? Akina I need to wrap my head around exactly what it is that you suggest. Can you elaborate a bit more and I don't know what an M:N model is, and how I'm supposed to list attribute type if more than one attribute can be selected?